# Detectar botón "atrás" (back button) de un celular con javaScript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, back-button, programación-móvil

Tengo una app web que se ve desde un webview y ésta es de chats (estilo whatsapp). Ya solucioné el problema de subir el contenido del chat (junto con el textarea para escribir el mensaje) X% cuando el input está en "focus". Sin embargo, y ya que eso no lo puedo hacer detectando cuando el softkey está abierto, cuando aprieto la tecla "back" del celular (que NO está en el teclado), el teclado se cierra y el contenido del chat sigue elevado. Por lo que necesito poder detectar cuando presiono dicha tecla para poder así bajar el contenido. Desde ya, gracias.

Comment: cuando dices webview es porque usas Apache Cordova quizas PhoneGap ?

Comment: No, solo uso Android Studio para hacer la app. Todo el código de la app es de una app web. O sea, la app android es solo una carcaza para mostrar mi app web.

Comment: Criss hay alguna razón que no te permita usar cordoba phonegap? porque realmente es muy sencillo detectar e prevenir el botón atras con el framework.

Comment: Es que no se nada de Android prácticamente. Recién ahora estoy aprendiendo algo. Y al no se una app nativa (es una web con diseño mobile para que parezca app nativa en el webview), todas las funcionalidades y eventos son JS de la misma página.

Comment: Criss por eso te lo digo, phonegap es un framework, las apps las puedes realizar con html, css y javascript, como tambien estar alojadas en un host, phonegap es como un webview, pero dopado http://phonegap.com/ y http://www.phonegapspain.com/

Comment: Pero puedo usar cordova en ve, de pgonegap in tener las mismas funcionalidades? Porque no tengo espacio en la pc para el eclipse y todo lo demás que se necesita (además de que no me dan loa tiempos de aprender phonegap).

Comment: ya que no es posible detectar el softkey, la solucion podria ser estimando cuando apareceria y desapareceria, usando los eventos onfocus y oninput de todos los input tipo text o textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según leo en stackoverflow en inglés ([aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600040/jquery-js-html5-change-page-content-when-keyboard-is-visible-on-mobile-devices)), la solución es no basarte en detectar un evento de cambio de historial, sino en detectar un evento de redimensionamiento del área visible (`resize`)

Comment: Lo que sucede es que un webview no se ve afectado (no se redimensiona, panea ni escrolea) cuando se abre el softkey. Por lo que no sirve detectar redimensiones.

Comment: En tal caso tendrás que hacer la detección a nivel de Java (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android), y propagar el evento hacia dentro del webview.

Comment: mmmm voy a revisarlo. De todas maneras ya solucioné el problema. Hice un teclado virtual prácticamente calcado del teclado de mi celular y "le di vida" (le puse todas las funciones de un teclado virtual nativo). Así que voy a desabilitar el softkey  y uso el mío. Muchas gracias igual! :D